# WINAPI: Get a List of Devices by their NT name

Tags: c, winapi, device

This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235128) explains how to Query logical DOS names for their NT naming convention using [**QueryDosDevice**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365461%28VS.85%29.aspx). It explains how to add and remove Logical Device names using their NT naming convention using [**DefineDosDevice**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363904%28VS.85%29.aspx). The article explains that a DOS name is required to access various devices.

> "Win32 programs cannot use internal
>   Windows NT device names to access
>   devices because the Win32 subsystem
>   and Win32 API require the more
>   familiar drive letters and MS-DOS
>   device names, such as A:, C:, COM1:,
>   and LPT1"

I found this [interesting article](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/tips/Mapping_NT_Device_Names/article.asp) that gets all the available DOS Names and then queries for the NT Name using the function [**GetLogicalDriveString**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364975%28VS.85%29.aspx). This article does not explain how to return all defined DOS names for devices, just drives.

However, I would like to know how to do the reverse. How would I get a list of NT device names. I am not looking for just drives but all devices. For example **LPT1** and **COM1** are reserved DOS names that correspond to specific NT names. I would like to map additional devices they may not have a DOS name so that I can use the WINAPI function [**CreateFile**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx).

**How do I get a list of all NT device names oppose to DOS Names?**

Comment: Is this even possible without using the Windows Driver Development Kit? I would like to keep with the regular WINAPI if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well underneath the hood the DosDevice's are symbolic links in the NT Object Manager database pointing to the underlying devices. I would recommend playing with [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx) to get a feel for how things are put together.

Unfortunately to do the enumeration yourself and to add your own custom symbolic links you would need to use the native NT apis (see [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/184416468) for abit on enumerating stuff). You can sometimes play some tricks with the DefineDosDevice function to do some mappings, however you don't actually need to do that if you just want to access objects through CreateFile. You can use the NT native escape syntax to access anything in the NT Object Manager database, just prefix your *native* path with `\\?\GLOBALROOT` and pass that to the CreateFile, e.g. if you want to access the floppy drive use `CreateFile(L"\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\Floppy0", ...);`

Comment: What if the symbolic link does not exist? I would like to create symbolic links dynamically. Perhaps a create a symbolic link for each device.

Comment: That is it NtQueryDirectoryObject where the buffer is set to OBJECT_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION 'Device'

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [`QueryDosDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365461%28VS.85%29.aspx) mention:

> *lpDeviceName* - This parameter can be NULL. In that case, the QueryDosDevice function will store a list of all existing MS-DOS device names into the buffer pointed to by lpTargetPath.
>
> *lpTargetPath* - If lpDeviceName is NULL, the function retrieves a list of all existing MS-DOS device names. Each null-terminated string stored into the buffer is the name of an existing MS-DOS device, for example, \Device\HarddiskVolume1 or \Device\Floppy0.

So have you tried doing:

```
QueryDosDevice(NULL, buffer, buffer_size);
```

That should get you a list of device names in the buffer.

Comment: That is definitely better than GetLogicalDriveStrings for MS-DOS names but it does not return the NT names.

Comment: @Shiftbit: What other devices are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The API you are looking for is WMI. Incidentally, that was already answered as well: [How do I list device types using WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596950/how-do-i-list-device-types-using-wmi)