# List connected peripheral devices

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on Windows 10 and I'm looking for a batch script command to get a list of all peripheral devices that are in my pc.

Does anyone know the command I'm looking for?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but if someone came from google and they wanted to get the peripheral list WINDOW, they can type "hdwwiz.cpl" or "devmgmt.msc"

Answer (score 1):

WMIC will give some spiffy info (I use it to inventory my company's PCs), but it won't list ALL installed devices. For that, you'll have to check the registry. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum` is probably the key/branch you're looking for, and you can use the `REG` command to query it, but you'll still need to loop through a bunch of keys and decide how much information your REALLY want. For example, do you really want to know about virtual devices like "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter" or the "Microsoft VHD Loopback Controller"? If you want to limit things to just "real" hardware, you'll STILL have to do a lot of sorting unless you really want all 2 or 4 processor cores listed (because each is its own device). You probably don't really need to know much about the System Timer device or the PIC.

If possible, you should use ANYTHING other than a command prompt batch file. Use [VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596950/how-do-i-list-device-types-using-wmi), [Powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/09/10/managing-hardware-devices-from-powershell.aspx), or even [Devcon](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311272).

Update: I just tested, and `reg query hklm\system\currentcontrolset\enum /s /f "DeviceDesc"` is the command you are looking for.